# ElectroMagnetic Induction

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

there is already a *electromagnetic brake*. I'm thinking to use a *electromagnetic induction* as brake. is it possible?

Comment: See "regenerative braking" or "back EMF braking". Connecting a small-value high-wattage resistor across a motor is a crude but effective inductive brake. Note you also need a mechanical "parking" brake.

Comment: @pjc50 How is a resistive shunt an inductive brake, or regenerative?

Comment: The _motor_ is inductive.

Comment: my design of brake rotor is like a rotor that slots are not *skewed*. I read that rotor slot are designed skewed to prevent motor locking. Maybe this locking serve as braker. is it right?

Answer (score 3):

Cars, electric trains, elevators, modern ones all use regenerative braking. In this case the electricity generated is fed back into batteries or the mains grid.

Another example is an electronic controlled hand drill / screwing machine. When you release the control push button the motor is effectively shorted  and is in turn used to brake its own rotation and it stops spinning very quickly. This is especially essential with screws as you would damage them or the material if you run them too deep/tight.

[Regenerative braking @wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_brake)

[Regenerative braking @howstuffworks](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/auto-parts/brakes/brake-types/regenerative-braking.htm)